# MSAL upgrade version for microsoft.bot.Connector nuget

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

My team is working on MSAL migration and we found "microsoft.bot.Connector" nuget is using ActiveDirectory reference internally.
What is the latest version of microsoft.bot.Connector nuget which is migrated for MSAL?
A sample code for latest version upgrade for MSAL will also help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the Dotnet SDK [releases](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases/tag/4.16.0), 4.16.0 is the most recent version to merge work on MSAL. Your screenshot shows version 4.14.4, which is too old to have those fixes. Please update to 4.16 or newer.